# How to change button ID to another ID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Based on my snippet code, I'm having error in TypeError because of ID is not exist, the button ID can be set in admin by **yes**, **no**, **disabled**,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("no").remove();
        document.getElementById("disabled").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('yes').setAttribute('id','<?php echo $update->update;?>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<button id="<?php echo $update->install;?>">Install</button>-->
<button id="disabled">Install</button>
```

My questions:

1) How to solve TypeError when ID is not exists?

2) How to show value of `<?php echo $update->update;?>` inside JavaScript?

Comment: `getElementByID` returns a `Null` when the element does not exist. use that in `if`condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `jQuery`, just use it to fix the `TypeError` issue. `jQuery` already does the checking.

You can `'<?php echo $update->update;?>'` to `echo` on js.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#no" ).remove();
     $( "#no" ).attr('id','done');
     $( '#disabled' ).prop('disabled', '<?php echo $update->update;?>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<button id="<?php echo $update->install;?>">Install</button>-->
<button id="disabled">Install</button>
```

---

**Note:** if you are trying to set the initial status of a button, it is recommended to set it on `php` and not on `jQuery`.

```
$status = "disabled";
echo '<button type="button" ' . $status . '>Click Me!</button>';
```

Comment: I changed it , now it's working. Thanks and thumps up for your clear answer.

Comment: Happy to help :)